# Delphi Fortes Report angleLabel on top, across a report

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

I am making the invoice part of an application, and at this moment I am done with the invoice generation (adding products and stuff).
The next step is to have a report displaying the invoice data, ready to print.
That works too. I used Fortes Reports because it is free, easy to work with, and has a free PDF export filter, and a Preview component, so it has everything I need.

Now, my problem is that I must allow my users to Annull an invoice. So when an invoice was emitted, if there was a problem with it, I cannot just delete it later, I must Annull it (I'm not sure that is how you call it - maybe make it void), but basically the invoice stays the same (in printed form) EXCEPT we must **write/draw diagonally on top of the entire invoice one word**: ANNULLED with RED color.

That means I will make a new report for this case (annulled invoices) and use this one whenever the user wants to print an annulled invoice

So now in Fortes Report there is an RLAngleLabel component that allows me (in theory) to do just that: draw/write the word ANNULLED on the report. But my problem is that I add the label just fine in the btDetail RLBand, only **I just can't see it in Preview**, and I have no idea what I am doing wrong. If it's not visible in designtime preview, I assume it wont be visible in runtime neither.
Should I place it in a specific way? Should I add it at runtime somehow? I cant seem to be able to access the report's Canvas so I could draw it in some event...
Does anyone have any experience with what I am describing?

*In order to reproduce my problem*, just add a RLReport control on your form, add bands to it (Titleband, ColumnHeaderBand, DetailBand), and on a detailBand (DetailGridBand)place an AngleLabel, then right click on the report and choose Preview...
If I place the AngleLabel on the TitleBand or on ColumnHeaderBand, then it shows in preview, except that I need to place this Angled label **ON TOP** of the contents of the invoice, not on the header info.

In the past I used a BMP image as big as the invoice (in order to have it transparent so I would see the contents beneath it), but that made my exported PDF report 5MB in size, and that is a little too much (PNG was not working correctly - I think it would not display it transparent or something like that, so I was stuck to using BMP).

Is there any way of achieving what I want (described above)?

Comment: Are you saying that it works in the printout ?  You can try adding it at runtime to see if it makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

For whoever encounters this dilema, I reached the conclusion that I should still go with displaying an image containing the desired text as background and setting the bands to Transparent.
The angleLabel approach seems to be unknown, so I dropped it.

I use this time a PNG file that is about 30-40 KB in size and that does not bother me to have it added to the size of the final PDF.
A lot better than the previous BMP image I used before (that increased the size of the PDF file with about 5 MB).

The neweest version of RLReports works with PNG images. That saved me

Also if you have any RLDraw objects on your report, you must set it's brush style to bsClear, so it would allow the background to be visible.